# Python docx installation isn't working due to unknown error on linux

Tags: python, pip, python-docx

I'm trying to install pip install python-docx but get the following error. Why doesn't it work?

```
building 'lxml.etree' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip_build_plakshma/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/opt/python2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -L/usr/lib64 -L. -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What Python and lxml versions are you using? What is your OS?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga), python2.7

Comment: You have built your own python2.7, but incorrectly, the lib is not correctly relocatable.

Comment: How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Type this in your terminal/cmd. 
`pip install python-docx`.

For me when I made typed it in the apple terminal it was an error but type in the Pycharm terminal and it should work.

Comment: please provide a complete solution / answer